# How do I fix this terminal overlapping in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio

[terminal letter overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNdQ8.png)

How do I fix this terminal overlapping in VS code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal Go to Edit-->Profile Preferences and in general tab check "Use System fixed width font"

Comment: Do I set it in the Mac terminal or VS code terminal preferences?

Comment: It's sounds like global problem, so I think in the Mac terminal.